# Connecting to zarafa with z-push with Java

Tags: wsdl

I'd like to connect to Zarafa/Z-push through my own client application. However, I cannot find the wsdl file on the server. For Microsoft Exchange, the URL should be http(s)://[servername]/ews/exchange.asmx
Does anybode know where to find the wsdl file on my Zarafa server?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a wsdl file for Z-Push. This is an ActiveSync implementation. The protocol specification is available at msdn.

There is a ews interface in development by Zarafa, but this is not publicly available yet.
Better to ask this kind of stuff in the Zarafa Forums: http://forums.zarafa.com